# Return the matched id contained in a sub-array provided by a json file

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a json file which looks like this :

```
{
  "Mappings": [
    {
      "LocalizedName": "39d256271e16456e8ec352c3cb87d778",
      "EnglishLocalizedName": "Default Outfit",
      "DevName": "Outfit_Alchemist_01",
      "IdRangeName": "OutfitEnum",
      "StackableRangeName": "Outfits",
      "StackableId": 300001
    },
    ...
     ,
}
```

My service which retreive the data looks like this :

```
return this.http.get(../assets/json/stackables.json).pipe(filter( (data) => data != null ))
```

And I want to know if a data["Mappings"][...]["StackableId"] exist and if so, just return the array.

But if I do :

```
this.http.get(../assets/json/stackables.json)["Mappings"].pipe(filter( (data) => data["StackableId"] === myId ))
```

It looks like the object is empty (maybe because of the async task)

How to manage this properly?

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to set the filter in your map:

```
http.get('../assets/json/stackables.json')
 .map(response => response.Mappings.filter(map => map.StackableId === myId))
```